# Python Script - Passing a string parameter fails in requests module( Curl Command)

Tags: python, splunk

**Sample Curl Command:**
curl "https://www.test.org:8088/services/collector/raw" -kH "Authorization: Splunk 999" -d '{"index":"abc","sourcetype":"dev","userName":"user1","lastActiveDate":1236472051.807}' 
**Issue :** 
1.When data=teststring is given (manually entered value), it works fine.
2.But when data=completeinfowithsyntax is given , it fails to send data.

**Python Program:**

```
import requests
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning

import calendar, time
from datetime import datetime

import re
import json

def convert_utc_to_epoch(lastActiveDate):
    timestamp = datetime.strptime(lastActiveDate, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000+0000")
    epoch = int(calendar.timegm(timestamp.utctimetuple()))
    return epoch

def getInfo():

    headers = {
    'Authorization': 'adc 12345'
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }

    userName_list , lastActiveDate_list = [] , []

    requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)
    response = requests.get('https://somewebsite.org', headers=headers, verify=False)
    Content = response.text

    userName = re.compile(r'.*"userName":"(.*?)"')
    userName_list = (userName.findall(Content)) if userName else ""

    lastActiveDate = re.compile(r'.*"lastActiveDate":"(.*?)"')
    lastActiveDate_list = (lastActiveDate.findall(Content)) if lastActiveDate else ""

    lastActiveDate = convert_utc_to_epoch(lastActiveDate_list[0])
    return userName_list[0],lastActiveDate

def sendDataToSplunk():

    headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Splunk 999',
    }

    RequiredData = getInfo()
    print(RequiredData)

    timeinttostr= str(RequiredData[1])
    completeinfo='"index":"abc","sourcetype":"dev","userName":"'+RequiredData[0]+'","lastActiveDate":'+timeinttostr
    print(completeinfo)
    completeinfowithsyntax="'{"+completeinfo+"}'"
    print(type(completeinfowithsyntax))
    print("completeinfowithsyntax",completeinfowithsyntax)

    teststring='{"index":"abc","sourcetype":"dev","userName":"user1","lastActiveDate":1579010706}'

    response = requests.post('https://www.test.org:8088/services/collector/raw', headers=headers, data=completeinfowithsyntax, verify=False)
    print("done")

sendDataToSplunk()
```

Comment: Can you post completeinfowithsyntax ? Maybe it contains single-quote or double-quote

Comment: What is `getInfo()`? Can you share that code?

Comment: when I print completeinfowithsyntax '{"index":"abc","sourcetype":"dev","userName":"user1","lastActiveDate":1579010706}'

Comment: getInfo would return ('user1', 1579010706)

Comment: Instead of doing your own string manipulation, have you considered using `json.dumps` to convert your data structure to a string?

Comment: Info={}

    RequiredInfo = getInfo()
    Info['index'] = "abc"
    Info['sourcetype'] = "dev"
    Info['userName'] = RequiredInfo[0]
    Info['lastActiveDate'] = RequiredInfo[1]

    data = json.dumps(Info)
    data="'"+data+"'"
    print(data)
    print(type(data))

Tried both the ways. It gives the same error.

Comment: You shouldn't need to put extra quotes around `data` anymore. It is already well formed.

Comment: Removed the extra quotes and tried. Still I keep getting the same error.

Comment: I am new to Python. Can someone please help me out to fix this isuse?